# using generic to pass multiple class in a function

Tags: java, generics

I have multiple enum classes implementing same interface say interface1.

```
enum classA implements interface1
enum classB implements interface1
enum classC implements interface1.
```

I want to write a function using generics where i can pass these classes using generics in varargs format. i have written a function but it can take only one class at time.

my implementation:

```
 <T extends Enum<T> & interface1> void getLinksUtils(
        Map<String, List<Link>> links,
        Class<T> configuration) {

                    ............ }
```

and calling it as :

```
getLinksUtils(myMap,classA.class);
getLinksUtils(myMap,classB.class);
getLinksUtils(myMap,classC.class);
```

but I want to make this function as i can pass class in below format :

```
getLinksUtils(myMap,classA.class,classB.class,classC.class);
```

Can somebody suggest me what changes should my make or any other interesting method to do it.

Comment: So you need a variadic method; nothing to do with generics.

Comment: How is this different from varargs, as you indicate you know about? You simply need `Class<?>...`

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code, we can't help you diagnose that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without more context I can't try it myself, but something like this should work in 1.5 or later:

```
 <T extends Enum<T> & interface1> void getLinksUtils(Map<String, List<Link>> links, T ... configurations) {
     //add code here
     }
 getLinksUtils(myMap,classA,classB,classC);
```

---

Edit:
This compiles with a warning, but I did have to weaken your Enum bound.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
interface Interface1{

}
enum ClassA implements Interface1{

}
enum ClassB implements Interface1{

}
class Link{

}
public class test {


     <T extends Enum<?> & Interface1> void getLinksUtils(Map<String, List<Link>> links, T ... configurations) {
         //add code here
     }
     static void main(String ...args){
         ClassA config1 = null;
         ClassB config2 = null;
         Map<String,List<Link>> links = null;
         (new test()).getLinksUtils(links,config1,config2);
     }

}
```

Comment: thanks.. but this doesn't works. i have tried this. Please tell me what further info you need. This class and interfaces are quite big in size posting all of them is bit tough.

Comment: I made some edits, is this closer to what you're looking for?